# How to convert base64 Image to File object so that I can Send it to Django ImageFeed

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch, expo, blob

I have expo project and Im using `expo-image-picker` to pick img from device, but it only retuns `uri and base64 data not actual File`, I need to send this image to `django` and it should validate as `ImageField`

I tried converting base64 to blob using b64-to-blob(npm) but atob is not available in react native android, I also tried creating Blog using fetch API but it gives `Network error` on Andoid

```
let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
            mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
            allowsEditing: true,
            aspect: [4, 3],
            quality: 0.5,
            base64: true,
        });
console.log(result) 
/*
{
height: "some num",
width: "some num",
...
uri: "file://file_in_device",
base64: "base64 string"
}
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

We have to use **multipart/form-data** to send files to API calls for sending images to the backend.

Like.

```
const data = new FormData()
data.append("image", {
  name: "test.jpg",
  type: "image/jpg",
  uri: result.uri
})

await fetch({
    url: 'API END POINT HERE',
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
    },
    body: data
})
```

Comment: uri is not a valid ImageFeed django says:  profile_pic: is Not a valid img, thats why posted his question  I need to convert it to File\